# Improve MySQL Slow Query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using new relic to diagnose and fix performance issues with our database. So I have the following query that is the most time consuming.

```
SELECT * FROM `page_view` 
WHERE `ip_address` = ?s 
  AND `param` = ?n 
  AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `page_view` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_pages` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `param` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `contract_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `listing_type_sid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_pages` (`id_pages`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  KEY `param` (`param`),
  KEY `contract_id` (`contract_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=207 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Am a novice when it comes to working with queries but I'd appreciate any tips to improve the performance of this one.

Thanks.

Comment: change `AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)` to `AND DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY) > NOW() ` and see if it makes some diff. Also use Explain to see whats going on.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, since your suggestion would make no difference, I think you mean `AND date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)`.

Comment: right my bad...the idea was to make the indexed col date in to operation !! but its not idexed in his table structure !! so adding that can improve

Comment: Thanks for this. Let me try this and I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an appropriate index.

And when possible, don't wrap columns in expressions in predicates, when an equivalent predicate on the bare column is available. For example, this:

```
NOW() < DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

can be replaced by this:

```
`date` > NOW() + INTERVAL -1 DAY
```

With the latter form, the right side gets evaluated once, and becomes a literal, and MySQL can consider an index range scan operation on the `date` column to satisfy the predicate.

With the prior form, that's forcing MySQL to evaluate the expression on the right side and compare the result to the literal for every single row (or, at least, every row that isn't filtered out by some other predicate.)

The most appropriate index for this query would be to have the columns with the equality predicates leading, followed by the column with the inequality:

```
... ON page_view (ip_address, param, `date`)
```

Comment: With only 207 rows in the table (if the AUTO_INCREMENT value in the create table statement is accurate), the query execution shouldn't be slow even without an index. We'd only expect for the query to be "slow" if there were a boatload of rows in the table. But even so, for a query pulling a small subset of rows, we'd like to see an execution plan that makes effective use of an index, rather than a full scan.

Comment: Spencer, this is the table structure as taken from the installation sql file, so the 207 figure is a sample data that gets inserted when you install the script itself. The approximate number of rows now is around 3 million.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have lots of rows in your table, but only some of them relate to a given IP adress and param one suggestion that probably helps speeding up you query:
Create a combined index on the fields in the where clause:

```
create index myindex on page_view(ip_address, param, date)
```

Then move you date arithmetic away from the date field (subtract one day from now instead of adding it to date column). 
The new index might decrease insert speed, since there is a new index that must be managed.

Comment: +1. Add appropriate index and rewrite predicate to enable index range scan.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. Let me try this as well and I'll post back the results.

Comment: Creating the index seems to be working very well on InnoDB/XtraDB tables but on the default myISAM its not. I get this error when I run the create index query:  Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes. Any idea why? Am also looking at switching the whole database from MyISAM to InnoDB apart from a few tables that have FULLTEXT indexes, and I don't think innoDB support that yet, though am open to correction.

Comment: That's a technical limitation of myISAM. Your field param and ip_address are 255 characters long which translates to a maximum of > 1000 bytes in UTF8 (which I assume you are using). Maybe shortening the fields is an option.

Comment: Yes, I am using UTF8, I think I'll go with changing the storage engine to innoDB. The benefits outweigh the disadvantages in my case.